How to choose default uninformative prior in the R Package BAS
I'm conducting a Bayesian multilevel logistic regression based on the Rpackage BAS. I'm a beginner in Bayesian statistics.
But in bas.glm, I don't understand and I don't know how to specify my prior. According to the documentation I need to choose on of the following prior options: "Prior on coefficients for model coefficients (except intercept). Options include
g.prior, CCH, robust, intrinsic, beta.prime, EB.local, AIC, and BIC.".
I would a default uninformative prior.
Could you help me please?

I do not know the package, but bas.glm seems to come with a default betaprior = CCH(alpha = 0.5, beta = as.numeric(nrow(data)), s = 0), modelprior = beta.binomial(1, 1),
